# LibreOffice Calc Macro doesn't insert new sheet

Tags: libreoffice

I have a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet and used **Record Macro** function to copy the current row to a new sheet and transpose from columns to rows.

I assigned the macro to the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and everything works except a new sheet isn't inserted and the paste occurs in the current sheet which disastrous.

Sample of main sheet with current row highlighted:

[image: IG Main]

Sample of result when manually copy, insert sheet, paste transpose and format:

[image: IG View]

Current macro which fails to insert new sheet and pastes into current sheet:

```
sub ViewRowInNewSheet
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem define variables
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem get access to the document
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "Sel"
args1(0).Value = false

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToStartOfRow", "", 0, args1())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args2(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args2(0).Name = "Sel"
args2(0).Value = true

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToEndOfRow", "", 0, args2())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Copy", "", 0, Array())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
'dim args4(1) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
'args4(0).Name = "Name"
'args4(0).Value = "View"
'args4(1).Name = "Index"
'args4(1).Value = 4

'dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Insert", "", 0, args4())
'
' Replacement Code from Ask Ubuntu March 6/2017 :
oSheets = ThisComponent.Sheets
oSheets.insertNewByName("View",1)

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args5(5) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args5(0).Name = "Flags"
args5(0).Value = "SVD"
args5(1).Name = "FormulaCommand"
args5(1).Value = 0
args5(2).Name = "SkipEmptyCells"
args5(2).Value = false
args5(3).Name = "Transpose"
args5(3).Value = true
args5(4).Name = "AsLink"
args5(4).Value = false
args5(5).Name = "MoveMode"
args5(5).Value = 4

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:InsertContents", "", 0, args5())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args6(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args6(0).Name = "ToPoint"
args6(0).Value = "$A$1"

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, args6())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args7(2) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args7(0).Name = "FontHeight.Height"
args7(0).Value = 15
args7(1).Name = "FontHeight.Prop"
args7(1).Value = 100
args7(2).Name = "FontHeight.Diff"
args7(2).Value = 0

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:FontHeight", "", 0, args7())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args8(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args8(0).Name = "By"
args8(0).Value = 1

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoDownSel", "", 0, args8())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args9(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args9(0).Name = "By"
args9(0).Value = 1

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoDownSel", "", 0, args9())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:DeleteRows", "", 0, Array())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args11(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args11(0).Name = "ToPoint"
args11(0).Value = "$A$3"

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, args11())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args12(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args12(0).Name = "Sel"
args12(0).Value = true

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToEndOfData", "", 0, args12())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args13(4) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args13(0).Name = "CharFontName.StyleName"
args13(0).Value = ""
args13(1).Name = "CharFontName.Pitch"
args13(1).Value = 1
args13(2).Name = "CharFontName.CharSet"
args13(2).Value = -1
args13(3).Name = "CharFontName.Family"
args13(3).Value = 0
args13(4).Name = "CharFontName.FamilyName"
args13(4).Value = "Andale Mono"

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:CharFontName", "", 0, args13())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args14(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args14(0).Name = "ToPoint"
args14(0).Value = "$A$3"

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, args14())


end sub
```

**NOTE:** When inserting a new sheet the default is to insert before the current sheet. I picked the option to insert the new sheet *after* the current sheet. I don't think that should effect anything though.

LibreOffice was updated a couple of weeks ago automatically to **Version 5.1.6.2**. I would be more than happy to downgrade if that fixes the problem but this is a new macro and I never tried it before the upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me using LibreOffice 5.3.0.3.  However it did not work using Apache OpenOffice 4.1.3.  So it seems to be a version-dependent problem.

UNO API calls are usually better than dispatcher calls, as recommended in a similar question here:

https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=26612

So if the "View" sheet has not been created yet:

```
oSheets = ThisComponent.Sheets
oSheets.insertNewByName("View",1)
```

Comment: I commented out the **Record Macro** lines (5 or 6 of them) and added your code in that section. I updated the question with your code. The sheet "View" is created but it doesn't get focus and the rest of the macro pastes over top of the active sheet. So I'm in the same situation, just cleaner with fewer lines. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, your code needs more changes.  Were you able to understand the code from the link in my answer?  If not, I could write a full working solution, although this week I'm pretty busy.  Maybe a bounty would help.  :)

Comment: Turns out I just needed to add a couple of declarations and this line: `dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:JumpToTable", "", 0, args15())`. I've upvoted and accepted your answer. Thanks for all your help.